# Approximate matches with bedtools intersect

Tags: vcf, bedtools

I am using `bedtools` to test whether a set of variant calls produced by a new method is missing any variants from a set of known validated variants.

```
bedtools intersect -v -a newcalls.vcf -b goldstandard.vcf
```

It's working as intended for SNV calls, but it occasionally misses indels due to a single base pair discrepancy. It's usually an alignment artifact that doesn't affect the interpretation of the variant.

My first thought was to make a BED file with intervals that extend a few bp beyond each variant call, and comparing *this* BED file to the known variants. However, I was wondering whether approximate matching is possible with `bedtools intersect`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `bedtools intersect` but first use `bcftools norm`.  [bcftools norm](http://www.htslib.org/doc/bcftools.html#norm) will left-align and normalize indels to get both vcf files consistent with each other.  This should resolve the matching if they are truly matching variants.

Comment: This could resolve some of the cases if the input files are not normalized. However, there could be indels that are normalized and 1 bp away from each other (*i.e.* close but not touching each other). In my understanding, the OP wants to consider these cases as genuine matches.

Comment: I will let the OP clarify but it seemed to me that these were matching variants just with alignment artifacts.  If that is true then they should normalize out.

Answer (score -1):

You could use `bedtools closest` with `-d` option (*-d: In addition to the closest feature in B, report its distance to A as an extra column.*). Indels that have no match in file A would be those where the closest indel in file B is more than *x* bases away.

Comment: You have to be careful here that you are not matching a snp with an indel or vise versa.